# What's the Mandarin equivalent of 埋 in Cantonese?

Tags: translation, topolect

For example (in Cantonese):

1. 記住帶埋手套
2. 走之前要閂埋房門
3. 佢跟埋我哋一齊去

What character can be used as 埋 in Mandarin?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/946/
>
> **埋**
>
> /maai4 /  jyutping
>
> /mai2/ /man2/   pinyin
>
> [1] [v] bury; cover up; lay sth underground
>
> [2] [v] conceal; hide; lie low
>
> [3] [粵] [v] finish up; close out; settle (an account)
>
> [4] [粵] [v] move closer/nearer to; close in/up
>
> [5] [粵] [adv] closer together; nearer to
>
> [6] [粵] [adv] even; too; also; as well

- In "記住帶**埋**手套", "**埋**" means "too"(see [6]) . In Mandarin, it is "**也**".
  The sentence would become "記住**也**帶手套"
- in "走之前要閂**埋**房門" , "**埋**" means "close in/up"(see [4]). In Mandarin, it is "**上**". The sentence would become "走之前要閂**上**房門"
- "佢跟**埋**我哋一齊去", "埋" means "as well" (see [6]).  In Mandarin, it is "**也**". The sentence would become "他**也**跟我們一起去"

More examples:

When **埋** = **finish up**

- Cantonese: 做**埋**啲功課先可以去玩。
- Mandarin: 做**完**那些功課才可以去玩。

When **埋** = **closer together**

- Cantonese: 你兩個企**埋**啲。
- Mandarin: 你們兩個站**近**點。

Answer (score 0):

埋 doesn't correspond to a single character in mandarin, but is more generic.

1. 带来
2. 闩好
3. (omit)